# Inclusion of interaction term and interpretation

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, predictor, association-measure

I'm planning to run a large amount of regressions to test for an association between medical conditions. As my dependent variable is always age-dependent, I include age as a covariate. For example, I wish to check if drinking regularly affects the risk of a heart attack, e.g.:

`heart_attack ~ age + drinker_status`

Now there is a possibility that `drinker_status` and `age` have an interaction. Ideally I would inspect the data and plot it, but I'm wondering if there is a systematic approach to deciding whether to include this interaction.

Based on discussions on CrossValidated and elsewhere, I've come across the following options:

1. Run each model with and without the interaction and choose based on AIC.
2. Run each model with and without the interaction and choose based on R².
3. Run each model with and without the interaction and choose based on p-value and/or coefficient of the interaction term (this one seems very arbitrary and did not find much support).
4. Always use the model with the interaction term so as to include the maximum of available information (This makes for more difficult interpretation of the association though, as some p-values become non-significant even for very biologically plausible dependent variables.

My aim is not the modelling of the e.g. heart-attack risk, but simply to test for an association of heart-attack and drinker-status. In my field it is customary to go almost exclusively by p-value cutoff. What would be a good way to go about this association testing it in this context?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. For me, there is another option. I would always include an interaction term if I have a *theoretical* reason to do so, no matter what the AIC, $R^2$ or *p*-value indicates. In the end, this interaction term might not work but that's the part of the empirical analysis.

Comment: Age is not linearly related to morbidity, so that is a wrinkle that should be addressed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you interested in? You say that you want to test an association between heart-attack and drinker-status, but if you are only interested in an association, why adjust for age at all?

If you are interested in a causal association, you will need more information: what are all relevant variables that may lead to confounding, are causal inference assumptions met, are you fitting the right model, etc.

Regardless, I would raise a 5th option: choose whether or not to add the interaction in the model based on your (and if applicable/available supervisors'/experts') knowledge. If you believe there is likely an interaction between drinker_status and age, then you should add it to your model. The reason for this 5th option is that your choice to include a variable/interaction is not data driven: the data you collected are a random subset of the total (theoretical supra)population and may therefore contain spurious associations or miss spurious associations, meaning the model you fit based on those data is not an actual representation of reality. For instance, you might adjust for an association in your data because this association was 'statistically significant' in the model, but are in truth adjusting for a variable that happens after the exposure and before the outcome, meaning you are adjusting part of the effect away.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You are correct, I am in fact interested in causal associations. Rather than heart attack risk, I'm aiming to test other understudied conditions for risk factors in a large cross-sectional dataset. In my case, age is the only (known) relevant variable, though there may be others that are undiscovered (that I hope to discover with my analysis). Consequently, nothing is known about possible interactions for most independent variables I wish to test. 
Do you have any suggestions how to do this correctly / in a data-driven way?

Comment: A causal association in a cross-sectional dataset is sadly impossible: given that both the exposure (from what I understand the risk factor) and the outcome (the understudied condition) were measured at the same time (making the data cross-sectional), we cannot determine which one came first. For instance, we cannot discern between 'increased biomarker X caused cancer' and 'cancer caused increased biomarker X'.

Comment: To causally identify an effect, we would need longitudinal data and meet certain assumptions, see also my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613290/expected-decrease-from-baseline-to-follow-up-linear-regression/613356#613356).

Nonetheless, you can use cross-sectional data to try and see if you have some associations that are independent for a number of known covariates, to inform future studies/feasability. It can make you start thinking about the causal structure of the association and data needed for a future study.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @rjjanse (+1) covers several important points. There's a fundamental problem with what you seem to be doing, however:

> I'm planning to run a large amount of regressions to test for an association between medical conditions.

That sounds like a whole series of individual outcome-versus-predictor regressions, controlling for `age` as a covariate. That will get you into trouble in several ways, in particular the [multiple-comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem), [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias), and the inability to identify associations with outcome that depend on combinations of predictors beyond `age`.

Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) provides much guidance on proper design. To understand the issues in causal analysis, read [Hernán and Robins](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/).